# Is there a way to pass multiple parameters to Quarkus resource with POST request?

Tags: java, rest, post, quarkus

I am developing an application using Quarkus which is based on the Java. I have a requirement where I would like to pass multiple parameters to my `Quarkus` based REST API. As of now everything works well when I pass a single parameter but when I increase the parameter then I get the error:

```
quarkus java.io.IOException can only have a single body parameter:
```

Can someone please let me know how can I pass multiple parameters to my quarkus application?

Following is the example code I have:

```
@Path("/api")
public class ExampleResource {

    @Path("/example")
    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String generate(@HeaderParam("Content-Type") String contentType, final String input1, final String input2, final String input3){
        System.out.println("Parameter 1 : " + contentType);
        System.out.println("Parameter 2 : " + input1);
        System.out.println("Parameter 3 : " + input2);
        System.out.println("Parameter 4 : " + input3);

        final MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
        return contentType.equals("application/xml") ? myObj.xmlMethod(input1, input2, input3) : myObj.jsonMethod(input1, input2, input3);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#accessing-the-request-body; you need to aggregate your `input-n` parameters in a single object and let Quarkus mapping it using JSON mapper

Comment: Where exactly are the parameters coming from? HTTP Body, Headers, something else?

Comment: @geoand Thanks a lot for the response. It is like I need to pass multiple parameters to my Quarkus service which will internally call the Java method by passing these parameters.  I have added an simple example code. Please see in the question.

Comment: I see the sample code, but it's not obvious where you expect `input1`, `input2` etc to be coming from.

Comment: @geoand It is user-provided meaning that users can either provide it in Quarkus Swagger-UI or using Postman or using the CURL command etc. Basically, users will provide different information.

Comment: Sure, but where does it come from? Query parameters, headers, request body?

Comment: I have the same issue when using `QueryParams`

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a good How-To.
This is for resteasy-reactive, but you should be able to use it for your needs.

xy-url.com/api/v1/foo?var1=111111111&var2=222222&var3=3333333

```
@GET
```

@Path("/api/v1/foo")
@Produces(MediaType.xxxxxx)
public void yourParameters(@QueryParam("code") String var1, @QueryParam("var2") String var2,@QueryParam("var3") String var3);

---

https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive

```
@POST
    public String allParams(@RestPath String type,
                            @RestMatrix String variant,
                            @RestQuery String age,
                            @RestCookie String level,
                            @RestHeader("X-Cheese-Secret-Handshake")
                            String secretHandshake,
                            @RestForm String smell) {
        return type + "/" + variant + "/" + age + "/" + level + "/"
            + secretHandshake + "/" + smell;
```

---

```
@Path("/cheeses/{type}")
```

public class Endpoint {

```
public static class Parameters {
    @RestPath
    String type;

    @RestMatrix
    String variant;

    @RestQuery
    String age;

    @RestCookie
    String level;

    @RestHeader("X-Cheese-Secret-Handshake")
    String secretHandshake;

    @RestForm
    String smell;
}

@POST
public String allParams(@BeanParam Parameters parameters) { 
    return parameters.type + "/" + parameters.variant + "/" + parameters.age
        + "/" + parameters.level + "/" + parameters.secretHandshake
        + "/" + parameters.smell;
}
```

Greetings.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a MessageBodyReader is what you are looking for.

You define a single Class for your input

```java
public class MyInput {
    public List<String> lines;
}
```

and a api method

```
@Path("/example")
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public String generate(@HeaderParam("Content-Type") String contentType, MyInput input){
    return String.join(",", input.lines);
}
```

and a message reader, which can convert text/plain to MyInput. In this case we just read all the lines from input.

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class MyInputReaderFromText implements MessageBodyReader {
    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class aClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return aClass.equals(MyInput.class);
    }
    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class aClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap multivaluedMap, InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        MyInput result = null;
        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
            result = new MyInput();
            result.lines = new LinkedList();
            while (reader.ready()){
                result.lines.add(reader.readLine());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot parse input");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now you can post a plain text with lines

```
line1
line2
```

or json like

```js
{
 "lines": ["line1", "line2"]
}
```